# MapKit avoid certain routes (highways, tolls, etc.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, swift, mapkit

Is this possible using the default Apple API's? I know it is with Google but I'd like to try to stick with Apple everything.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/), it doesn't look like neither `MKRoute` nor `MKDirectionsRequest` have related API for such things.